# how to get a new value while parsing JSON?

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, async-await, adaptive-cards

Am trying to get data from an adaptive card (the name first) inside an async function and post it on mysql database. While using a post request i just get "{"name":""}" while parsing it. How do i properly fill this value?

```
   async register(context) {

        app.use(express.json());
        app.use(bodyparser.json());

        const SelectedCard5 = CARDS5[0];
        await context.sendActivity({
              text: 'processLogin(context)',
              attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(SelectedCard5)]
        })


 await context.sendActivity
 app.post('/id', async (req, res) => {
            app.use(express.json());
            app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
            const fs = require('fs');

 req.body = require('../Register.json');

                      var name = req.body.actions[0].$data["name"];
                      let username = '{"name":""}';
                      let z = JSON.stringify(name).replace(true, username);
                      let zz = JSON.parse(username);


  mysqlConnection.query("INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES('" + username + "')", function (err, result) {
  console.log("Yeah! record inserted");
                console.log(z);
                console.log(zz);
            }); res.send(username);
     });
    } }
        //the JSON field am trying to replace>>>>>>>>>
       "actions": [
            {
             "type": "Action.Submit",
             "title": "add new user",
             "$data": {
             "name": true,
             "email": true,
             "password": true
               }
            },
```

Comment: How does this question relate to phpMyAdmin? What have you tried to debug your problem?

Comment: Hi, i reformulated the question. Am testing the project in bot framework and "posting" results with postman.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` would not output `[object][object]`...instead you'd get a JSON representation of the variable. `console.log` might output something like that, if you try to log a whole complex object to a text output - it has no idea what format you want to present the various properties of the object (where in contrast, when you use JSON.stringify, you told it to use JSON format, so it knows exactly how the display the data). Which line of your code exactly is outputting `[object][object]`?

Comment: P.S. `var name = req.body.actions;` really makes no sense. `req.body.actions` is an array...yet you seem to be treating it as if it's going to output a single string containing a name. Did you mean to access the "name" property of the `$data` object which is itself within the the first object within the `actions` array? (Although I note that this field is actually blank anyway in your sample data..)

Comment: i changed it to "var name = req.body.actions[0].$data["name"];" and is accessing the field. Now trying to replace it´s "true" value seems to be the problem.